# R string vector to HTML text through for loop

Tags: r

Say I got this vector:

```
vector <- c("string_1", "string_2", "string_3")
```

I want to transform it to the following single string (note that the last line does not have the break tag).

```
"<h1>'string_1'</h1><br/>
<h1>'string_2'</h1><br/>
<h1>'string_3'</h1>"
```

How would you do this? 
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `paste` with `collapse`

```
paste0("<h1>", vector, "</h1>", collapse = "<br/>")
#[1] "<h1>string_1</h1><br/><h1>string_2</h1><br/><h1>string_3</h1>"
```